# Django psycopg2 error while migrating the project. Solved

Tags: django, psycopg2, django-migrations, migrate, makemigrations

The following error occurs while doing manage.py migrate.

**psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "*relation_name*" does not exist**
...
...
...
**django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "*relation_name*" does not exist**

Happened when I tried to set up a copy of my project elsewhere.
Yes, I have installed all the dependencies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Error caused by missing migrations folder.
Steps:

- Create a folder 'migrations' in the app folder.
  eg: if you have app called students, create it inside that folder.
- Create '**init**.py'
  This is critical as django won't look inside folders without the init file.
- Now perform makemigrations and migrate.

**Note:** If you have more than one app, create this folder inside every app.

This fixed it for me. Hope it helps someone out there as well.